# What is the point of using 'step_angle' and 'step_length' when making a function to draw an arc using Python turtle?

Tags: python, drawing, turtle-graphics

I am currently trying to work through thinkpython and I've come across this exercise which uses the turtle module to draw an arc, given radius and angle.

'Polyline' is a function which draws 'n' line segments (e.g. polyline(t, 5, 60, 72) draws a pentagon with 5 sides [line segments], each of length 60 pixels. The angle between each pair of sides is 72 degrees.

The 'arc' function calculates 'n' using int(arc_length / 4) + 1.

Why is 'n' equal to this? Further, it calculates a 'step_length' and a 'step_angle'. I am completely lost on what this means and what the significance of it is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here are the functions:

```
def polyline(t, n, length, angle):
    """
    Draws n line segments.

    t: Turtle object
    n: number of line segments
    length: length of each segment
    angle: degrees between segments
    """
    for i in range(n):
        fd(t, length)
        lt(t, angle)

def arc(t, r, angle):
    """Draws an arc with the given radius and angle.

    t: Turtle
    r: radius
    angle: angle subtended by the arc, in degrees
    """
    arc_length = 2 * math.pi * r * abs(angle) / 360
    n = int(arc_length / 4) + 1
    step_length = arc_length / n
    step_angle = float(angle) / n

    # making a slight left turn before starting reduces
    # the error caused by the linear approximation of the arc
    lt(t, step_angle/2)
    polyline(t, n, step_length, step_angle)
    rt(t, step_angle/2)
```

Comment: Consider [edit]ing the post to fix your indentation next time. Where's `polyline`? I think you're confusing that func with `polygon`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I noticed polyline - it was a separate function but I took it out to simplify the problem in the question. I've replaced it with a 'for' loop. Does it clear things a bit?

Comment: Not really, because `polygon` is never called by `arc`, so your question doesn't make sense, unless I'm misunderstanding things.

Comment: You're completely right. Sorry for the mix-up, huge oversight on my part. I've included polyline and wrote an explanation on how it works. Let me know if it's clearer. Appreciate your patience on this :)

Answer (score 0):

The step angle and step length are two important parameters that affect the appearance of an arc drawn by a turtle. The step angle determines the amount that the turtle turns after drawing each segment of an arc, while the step length determines the distance that the turtle moves forward after drawing each segment. A smaller step angle or step length will result in a smoother arc, but it will also take longer to draw.

Comment: did you use chatgpt at all to write any part of this answer?

Comment: no i didn't use chatgpt